# Ember incorrectly deserialize json data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

So I have a Spring Boot api returning a bunch of records in a list, like that:

```
[
  {
    "uid": 16587783,
    "createdAt": 1391708660000,
    "name": "FRaaS",
    "fullName": "caarlos0/FRaaS",
    "description": "Fake RT as a Service",
    "homepage": "http://fraas.herokuapp.com/",
    "owner": "caarlos0",
    "organization": null,
    "joined": false,
    "private": false
  },
  ....
  more records
]
```

but when I try to read it in the template, I get the following error

```
WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model name "0" (resolved model name using chathub-ember@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("0"))
```

Here is my current adapter

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1',
  primaryKey: 'uid',
  headers: Ember.computed('session.data.authenticated.currentUser.backendAccessToken', function() {
    return {
      "Auth-Token": this.get("session.data.authenticated.currentUser.backendAccessToken"),
    };
  })
});
```

what can I do in ember to allow it to read the data as I sent? I can change the API if needed, but I would rather not to

Comment: is that the complete (apart from repetition of course) payload/json you get from your api? If so, then you'd need to add a modelname at top of your payload. like `{ "modelNamePlural": [{"uid": 123456,....}]}`

Comment: yes, that is complete...I'll try add the model name then. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You need to use `RESTSerializer`. And `primaryKey` is for serializer not adapter. I think you use json serializer in your app.</s>

**UPDATE**

Add below to your application serializer

```
normalizeSingleResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        let typeKey = primaryModelClass.modelName;
        let ret = {};
        ret[typeKey] = payload;
        return this._normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, ret, id, requestType, true);
    },

    normalizeArrayResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        let pluralTypeKey = Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize(primaryModelClass.modelName);
        let ret = {};
        ret[pluralTypeKey] = payload;
        return this._normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, ret, id, requestType, false);
    }
```

Comment: what do I need to do in the `RESTSerializer`? Because I'm using it already but nothing changes

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you can help, but I got a new problem that seems related to the serialization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816571/ember-cannot-read-relationships